# Get product-wise sold quantity

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm exporting Magento products data for a non-Magento site. In this new site, I need to display product-wise sold quantity.

Eg. 23 sold out of 50

With Magento products table, I can get product current quantity. To fulfill my above need, I need another quantity which may be product original quantity or product sold quantity at this stage. I was not able to find an answer for my exact problem.

I guess this is something really simple. However I need some help and I don't have any Magento experience.

Comment: can you display completed order products qty or all orders status?

Comment: Sorry, I didn' t get what you said. Actually my problem is something not related to customer orders or order statuses. I need to get sold quantity with available quantity for each product. Sold quantity is the thing I need to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you ordered qty in collection. you can create custom file to export data this way to get ordered qty of products.

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
       ->addOrderedQty()
       ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');

foreach ($products as $_product)
{
   print_r($_product->getData());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got my problem solved with some modifications to your code.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all,Magento `did not save Inventories changes at history` in
   it system.

   For your requirement,you can get total no of sold qty by below code:

> ```
> $collection= Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')
>             ->setStoreId(1)->addStoreFilter(1)->addOrderedQty()
>        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
> $collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id = ?', $productId=400);
> echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
> $Sold=$collection->getFirstItem();
> echo $Sold->getOrderedQty();
> ```

2. Also, it *`sold qty does not depends on current available qty`* because
   of if **Manage Stock is enable** then *magento   is deduce on qty
   from system whenever an order is placed* and it update qty of product to magento is replace   current qty which this qty.It did not add with  old qty.

**Suppose**,your current *`A product  have qty 10`*,,Then you update qty **`30then magento does not change qty to 40.It replace to 30.`**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find sold qty by looping through products and using product sku.

```
$sku = "cs-68";
 $qty = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
 ->addOrderedQty()
 ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
->getFirstItem()
->ordered_qty;

echo 'Already Bought '.(int)$qty;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to show in qty product sold in magento 2?